# User Profile Controller Rspec Test Fails due to route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec, devise

I'm having a problem testing my new user profile page with Rspec. It's working through the browser, but Rspec is blowing up.

I'm using devise with a separate controller for editing profile fields.

This is a request spec.

```
    it 'Shows the user profile with their non-private data' do
      visit user_path(@user)
      page.should have_content @user.full_name
    end
```

Fails with this error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit user_path(@user)
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

I disagree

```
#routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  resources :users, :only => [:edit, :update, :show]
```

The update and edit path helpers are working just fine.

The controller action:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      layout 'profile', :except => [:show]
      #... edit and update omitted

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

rake routes shows:

```
                                new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                      devise/sessions#new
                  user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                      devise/sessions#create
          destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                     devise/sessions#destroy
                 user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                     devise/passwords#create
             new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                 devise/passwords#new
            edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                devise/passwords#edit
                               PUT    /users/password(.:format)                     devise/passwords#update
      cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                       registrations#cancel
             user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                              registrations#create
         new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                      registrations#new
        edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                         registrations#edit
                               PUT    /users(.:format)                              registrations#update
                               DELETE /users(.:format)                              registrations#destroy
                     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                     users#edit
                          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#show
                               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
```

So it doesn't really look like devise is interfering with my route, and more importantly, everything works in the browser. What am I missing here?

I also tried making a member action called profile instead of the default show, that had the same result

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was I started a new `context` block and didn't set up `@user` before the `it` block. The route thing was just a red herring.

Also proof that you should walk away from your code for awhile if you can't figure things out.